# Convert gps_common/GPSFix to sensor_msgs/NavsatFix ERROR

Tags: ros, gps-common, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to convert datas wich have the type gps_common/GPSFixpublished to sensor_msgs/NavsatFix using [gps_common](https://github.com/swri-robotics/gps_umd) but I get this error `[ERROR] [1523278560.370485801]: Client [/fix_translator] wants topic /gps_fix to have datatype/md5sum [gps_common/GPSFix/3db3d0a7bc53054c67c528af84710b70], but our version has [gps_common/GPSFix/4018f638cb28b3222ad792aeab48f1b5]. Dropping connection.` note that the datas are published by a bag file.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288031/convert-gps_common/gpsfix-to-sensor_msgs/navsatfix-error/) by [haysgh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28793/haysgh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-04-09**:
Is the version of `gps_common` that you have installed locally the same as the version of `gps_common` which was installed on whatever device was used to collect the bagged data?

**Comment by [haysgh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28793/haysgh/) on 2018-04-10**:
I don't have an idea about the version of `gps_common` used to collect the data. Assuming the two versions are different, is there a solution to overcome this problem like using another tool to do the conversion or creating my own node.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-04-10**:
There's some info [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosrecord#Fixing_md5sums_after_a_move_or_rename) on fixing md5sums in bag files. You could also upload a piece of the bag file so others can test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) for your answer. I managed to solve the problem by getting an old version of the package and add the fix_translator node because it was not included in the first releases. Also I think for others who might encounter the same problem and who don't want to waste their time in adding fix_translator node manually maybe a small change in the .xml file will solve the issue just change this line   `<version>0.1.7</version>` and put the right version used in your bag file.

---

Originally posted by [haysgh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28793/haysgh/) with karma: 28 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0